# To Form Mysql Query for leave checking

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling to modifying a query for Leave Request Query.

My Old Query:

```
SELECT * FROM #table_name 
WHERE ((from_date<='#date' AND to_date>='#date')
OR (from_date>='#date' and to_date<='#date') 
OR (from_date BETWEEN '#date' AND '#date' OR to_date BETWEEN '#date' AND '#date'))) 
AND employee_id = '#employee_id '
```

- This query working fine for checking whether leave is taken on those date and  it not allow to take half day leave on same date.

**For Example**

I'm taking leave from 01-02-2018 to 05-02-2018 (on 05-02-2018 I'm taking only first half of day).

So above query not allow me to take leave on second half of 05-02-2018.

**Constrains I have to add in that query:**

- I also have to check for half day leave.

Comment: You did not tell us how you are storing half day leaves (how do you (or your app) know that 05-02-2018 is a half day leave), which makes it guesswork to modify the query to include that information. One way you could store that is to include the time in the date(time)  (e.g. "2018-02-05 12:00:00"). This would have the advantage that you would not even need to change that query.

Comment: Sorry for that we are storing half day leave using (from_half_day and to_half_day) fields. Those fields are binary field. If 1 means half day leave and 0 means full day leave. We can take half day leave either from day or to day. Hope you understand now

Comment: **Suddenly adding time in the date fields would leads to more problem**. So can you help me to form a query with above information.